# 1 broadcast receiver instance at any given time

Tags: android

Currently, I have a broadcast receiver which will be executed when there is network activity changes.

```
    <receiver android:name="org.yccheok.jstock.network.ConnectivityChangeBroadcastReceiver" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.net.conn.CONNECTIVITY_CHANGE" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
```

However, sometimes, there will be a long running operation within ConnectivityChangeBroadcastReceiver. If the user tend to change the network connectivity several times within short time frame, several instance of broadcast receiver will be spawned.

I only wish to run 1 ConnectivityChangeBroadcastReceiver at any given time. Is there any technique I can apply?

Comment: Maybe you can create a Singleton class not the BroadcastReceiver?

Comment: Why not move long-running operation to Service and let BroadcastReceiver to do only fast operations as it should based on docs?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on [the documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/BroadcastReceiver.html):

> for receivers that may require the creation of a process, only one
>   will be run at a time to avoid overloading the system with new
>   processes

So, usage of [android:process](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/R.styleable.html#AndroidManifestReceiver_process) would block creation of two receivers.

However, it might be more flexible to maintain a `Service` and just send intents to it from brodcast receiver. That Service would be able to do necessary sorting / declining of handling / quering of incoming intents.

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn't be doing long-running tasks inside a `BroadcastReceiver`. Instead, start a service to do the long-running task as described [here.](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/BroadcastReceiver.html#ProcessLifecycle)

Answer (score 0):

use a flag and rise it when the broadcast receiver is called and lower it when the work is over so that no new instance can call the broadcast receiver

Answer (score -1):

You could just a static boolean field in your ConnectivityChangeBroadcastReceiver to keep track of whether the method is currently executing.

```
public class ConnectivityChangeBroadcastReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
    private static boolean currentlyReceiving = false;

 @Override
 public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
     if(!currentlyReceiving) {
        currentlyReceiving = true;
        doYourLongTaskHere();
        currentlyReceiving = false;
     }
  }
}
```

I'm not sure if every broadcast will be run in a different thread or not, so you may want to throw the block within the if statement into a synchronized block.